# Oracle : encrypting passwords

Tags: java, oracle, encryption, blowfish

Du to some tables with passwords in clair, I made un upgrade to a java application where the future passwords will be encrypted.

But before releasing this version, I do need to encrypt the existants passwords.

So is there a way in in a pl/sql Oracle to encrypt a password in clair from a string to Blowfish string and finaly to an hex string ?

The java code that is below:

```
public static String crypt(String plaintext) throws GinException
{
    return toHexString(crypt(plaintext.getBytes()));
}

private static byte[] crypt(byte[] plaintext) throws GinException
{
    try
    {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        return cipher.doFinal(plaintext);    
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new GinException(e.getMessage());
    }
}


// Convert a byte array to a hex string.
private static String toHexString ( byte[] b )
{
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer( b.length * 2 );
    for ( int i=0; i<b.length; i++ )
    {
        // look up high nibble char
        sb.append( hexChar [( b[i] & 0xf0 ) >>> 4] ); // fill left with zero bits

        // look up low nibble char
        sb.append( hexChar [b[i] & 0x0f] );
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: `DBMS_CRYPTO` is a good starting point. Check this link -> https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_crypto.htm#BJFGFDFG

Comment: Passwords should **not** be encrypted, they should be **hashed**. You shouldn't be confused about this; if you are, I hope you are not in charge of password security in any environment I may access myself, now or in the future.

Answer (score 0):

you can call Java from PL/SQL.  It's not too complicated, but you'll have to do your research to find the exact process.
if you are not restricted to encryption algorithm, you can use other, for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Cryptit AS
   FUNCTION encrypt( Str VARCHAR2 ) RETURN RAW;
   FUNCTION decrypt( xCrypt VARCHAR2 ) RETURN VARCHAR2;
   FUNCTION encrypt_with_key( Str VARCHAR2, key VARCHAR2 ) RETURN RAW;
   FUNCTION decrypt_with_key( xCrypt VARCHAR2, key VARCHAR2 ) RETURN VARCHAR2;
END Cryptit;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Cryptit AS
   crypt_raw RAW(2000);
   crypt_str VARCHAR(2000);

   -- Encrypt the string --
   FUNCTION encrypt( Str VARCHAR2 ) RETURN RAW AS

   l INTEGER := LENGTH(str);
   i INTEGER;
   padblock RAW(2000);
   Cle RAW(8) := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('frankzap');

   BEGIN
      i := 8-MOD(l,8);
      padblock := utl_raw.cast_to_raw(str||RPAD(CHR(i),i,CHR(i)));

      dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.DESEncrypt(
               input     => padblock,
               KEY       => Cle,
               encrypted_data => crypt_raw );
      RETURN crypt_raw ;
   END;

   -- Encrypt the string with user supplied encryption key --
   FUNCTION encrypt_with_key( Str VARCHAR2, key VARCHAR2 ) RETURN RAW AS

   l INTEGER := LENGTH(str);
   i INTEGER;
   padblock RAW(2000);
   Cle RAW(8) := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(key);

   BEGIN
      i := 8-MOD(l,8);
      padblock := utl_raw.cast_to_raw(str||RPAD(CHR(i),i,CHR(i)));

      dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.DESEncrypt(
               input     => padblock,
               KEY       => Cle,
               encrypted_data => crypt_raw );
      RETURN crypt_raw ;
   END;

   -- Decrypt the string --
   FUNCTION decrypt( xCrypt VARCHAR2 ) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
   l NUMBER;
   Cle RAW(8) := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('frankzap');
   crypt_raw RAW(2000) := utl_raw.cast_to_raw(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(xCrypt)) ;
   BEGIN
      dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.DESDecrypt(
               input     => xCrypt,
               KEY       => Cle,
               decrypted_data => crypt_raw );
      crypt_str := utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(crypt_raw);
      l := LENGTH(crypt_str);
      crypt_str := RPAD(crypt_str,l-ASCII(SUBSTR(crypt_str,l)));
      RETURN crypt_str;
   END;

      -- Decrypt the string with user supplied decryption key --
   FUNCTION decrypt_with_key( xCrypt VARCHAR2, key VARCHAR2 ) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
   l NUMBER;
   Cle RAW(8) := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(key);
   crypt_raw RAW(2000) := utl_raw.cast_to_raw(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(xCrypt)) ;
   BEGIN
      dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.DESDecrypt(
               input     => xCrypt,
               KEY       => Cle,
               decrypted_data => crypt_raw );
      crypt_str := utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(crypt_raw);
      l := LENGTH(crypt_str);
      crypt_str := RPAD(crypt_str,l-ASCII(SUBSTR(crypt_str,l)));
      RETURN crypt_str;
   END;

END Cryptit;
/
```

usage:

```
-- CRYPTIT functions usage example: 
set echo on
set feedback on
set serveroutput on

DECLARE
    LC$Code VARCHAR2(100) := 'Music is the best!' ;
BEGIN
    -- Get the encrypted string --
    LC$Code := Cryptit.Encrypt_with_key( LC$Code, 'yojoMama' ) ;
    dbms_output.put_line( LC$Code ) ;

    -- Get the decrypted string --
    LC$Code := Cryptit.Decrypt_with_key( LC$Code, 'yojoMama' ) ;

    dbms_output.put_line( LC$Code ) ;

END ;  
/


create table conn_string
(

username varchar2(30),
crypt_conn varchar2(100),
instance varchar2(15)
)
;

insert into conn_string 
values('CS_NOTEBOOK9', Cryptit.Encrypt_with_key('elnbukd452', 'yojoMama' ), 'UKDEV452')
;

insert into conn_string 
values('CS_NOTEBOOK9', Cryptit.Encrypt_with_key('elnbukt452', 'yojoMama' ), 'UKTST452')
;

insert into conn_string 
values('CS_NOTEBOOK9', Cryptit.Encrypt_with_key('elnbukv452', 'yojoMama' ), 'UKVAL452')
;

insert into conn_string 
values('CS_NOTEBOOK9', Cryptit.Encrypt_with_key('elnbukt452', 'yojoMama' ), 'UKTRN452')
;

insert into conn_string 
values('CS_NOTEBOOK9', Cryptit.Encrypt_with_key('elnbprd10', 'yojoMama' ), 'UKPRD452')
;

insert into conn_string 
values('CS_LTA', Cryptit.Encrypt_with_key('elnbprd10', 'yojoMama' ), 'UKPRD452')
;

select
username
, crypt_conn 
, Cryptit.Decrypt_with_key(crypt_conn, 'yojoMama' ) decrypt
, instance
from conn_string
;

rename conn_string to test_connect_details
;

create table test_set
( test_set_name varchar2(100)
, description varchar2(1000)
)
;


create table test_case 
( test_set_name varchar2(100)
, test_name varchar2(100)
, description varchar2(1000)
)
;

create table test_piece 
( test_set_name varchar2(100)
, test_name varchar2(100)
, piece_type varchar2(10)
, piece_order number (6,3)
, piece_text varchar2(4000)
)
;


select 'SQLPLUS ' || username 
|| '/' || Cryptit.Decrypt_with_key(crypt_conn, 'yojoMama' ) 
|| '@' || instance 
|| ' ' || (select piece_text from test_piece b) cmd

from test_connect_details a
where upper(username) = 'CS_NOTEBOOK9'
and upper(instance) = 'UKDEV452'  
;


select to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') date_run
, user
, instance_name 
from v$instance;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm restricted to Blowfish encryption algorithm. I can't change it.

Comment: @kkung, Therefore I would suggest looking into how to load your Java classes into the JVM implemented in the Oracle kernel.  Then your java code can be wrappered as a PL/SQL procedure.  Plenty in the Doc's on this, but too much to say here.